# How !+[] expression works in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm investigating why

```
!+[]
```

in javascript returns true. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Try `+[]` individually, the `!` is easy then.

Comment: `+[] = 0`, `!+[]` equals `!0 = true`

Comment: `!+[]` can be interpreted as `NOT` of `Number` conversion of `String` value of `Array` i.e. `!(Number([].toString()))`  = `!(Number(""))` = `!0` = `true`

Comment: May I recommend - https://github.com/denysdovhan/wtfjs for more of these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` is used to force numerical casting of a value and `!` negates an expression.

So in this example it'd be

`+[] = 0
!0 = true`